# gtk+ programming: arguments to callback functions

Tags: c, gtk, gnome, gtk3

The following code snippet is from the [GTK+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B) 3 tutorial from GNOME given [here](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html).

```
static void
print_hello (GtkWidget *widget,
             gpointer   data)
{
  g_print ("Hello World\n");
}

static gboolean
on_delete_event (GtkWidget *widget,
                 GdkEvent  *event,
                 gpointer   data)
{
  g_print ("delete event occurred\n");
  return TRUE;
}
```

The program is very simple, and it only has a toplevel window and a button. And this is how the callbacks have been connected:

```
 g_signal_connect (window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK (on_delete_event), NULL);
 g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
 g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (print_hello), NULL);
 g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), window);
```

My question is regarding the arguments we pass to the callback functions. Why is it that in the on_delete_event handler we pass the second argument GdkEvent* data?

Alternatively, why do we pass no such argument to the first callback function. What is the use of the GdkEvent parameter in this scenario?

I'm sorry if the question shows lack of research, but for me neither the tutorial, nor [the resource on event structures](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Event-Structures.html) was clear enough in describing callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signals have different signatures, just like functions have different signatures.

In the example above: The `event` family of signals on the `GtkWidget` class have, usually, associated a `GdkEvent` instance that details the event as received from the windowing system.

Still in the example above: The `clicked` signal is emitted by the `GtkButton` in response to a sequence of events: a button press, followed by a button release within the responsive area of the widget itself (that is, if you press the pointer button on the `GtkButton` widget, then you move the pointer outside the button widget and release the pointer button, and the `GtkButton` widget will not emit the `clicked` signal). For this reason, there is no `GdkEvent` instance associated to it.

It usually helps, when trying to understand them, to consider GObject signals as named lists of functions that can be invoked by a particular instance of a type.

Comment: but assuming that i release within the responsive area,`clicked` event will be triggered , so why does `print_hello` not accomodate for this event ,i mean why does that not have a GdkEvent argument?

Comment: because the clicked signal is not an event-related signal. :-) you can cause its emission programmatically (in some limited cases) or as a result of an accessibility request. if you want the event structure, you can connect the button-release-event on the button widget.

Comment: sorry didn't get it initially , so `on_delete_event` has a `GdkEvent` associated with it because we are connecting it to the window as well?

Comment: no, `GtkWidget::delete-event` is a signal emitted in response to an event coming from the windowing system, which means it has a `GdkEvent` associated with it.